# Usage of で in this sentence

Tags: grammar, particle-で

I have a sentence (jlptN4):

> その花屋はいつもきれいな花でいっぱいです。

Could someone please explain why it needs で here, not が?

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/20924/7810

Answer (score 1):

> その花屋はいつもきれいな花**で**いっぱいです。
> その花屋はいつもきれいな花**が**いっぱいです。

Both sound good to me.

「XXでいっぱい(だ)」 means "(something is) full of XX" "(something is) filled with XX".
「XXがいっぱい(だ/ある)」 means *lit.* "XX is many" → "there are many XX".

So the former literally means:
"The flower shop is always full of beautiful flowers."
And the latter:
"As for the flower shop, there're always a lot of beautiful flowers."

You can also say:

> その花屋にはいつもきれいな花がいっぱいです/あります。

*lit.* "In the flower shop, there are always a lot of beautiful flowers."

Comment: I've deleted my (obviously wrong) answer, but could you comment on where the flaw in my logic was please?

Comment: @user3856370, う～ん... 「いっぱい」 can mean 「満ちている」(full/filled) and 「たくさんある」(many). So, お腹がいっぱいだ is "full", 店が(花で)いっぱいだ is "full", and (店は)花がいっぱいだ is "many"... って感じでしょうか。

Comment: that's very interesting! thank you for the answer!